# AS2 Extract top 5 from array

Tags: arrays, flash, charts, actionscript-2

Good evening everyone!
Anyone knows how to extract the top 5 numbers (the highest) from an array?
I have an XML with names, surnames and score and want to extract the top 5 to create a chart.
As for now, I am getting all the info in this way:

```
num = xmlData.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num - 1; i++)
    {
        names[i] = this.childNodes[i].childNodes[6].firstChild.nodeValue;
        surnames[i] = this.childNodes[i].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
        points[i] = this.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        pointsint[i] = parseInt(speeds[i]);
        trace(i + "." + pointsint[i] + " (" + names[i] + " " + surnames[i] + ")");
    }
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Organize data as generic object entries and **Array.sortOn(...)** (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7ea5.html). I didn't test it but I think the idea is clear:

```
var num = xmlData.childNodes.length;
var entries = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= num - 1; i++)
{
    var anEntry = {};
    var aNode = xmlData.childNodes[i];

    anEntry['name'] = aNode.childNodes[6].firstChild.nodeValue;
    anEntry['surname'] = aNode.childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;

    var aSpeed = aNode.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    anEntry['speed'] = parseInt(aSpeed);

    entries.push(anEntry);

    trace(i + "." + anEntry['speed'] + " (" + anEntry['name'] + " " + anEntry['surname'] + ")");
}

entries.sortOn("speed", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
// Now first five elements of entries Array is what you want.
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code, it gives me back the array however it does not order it by placing at the top the highest score. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DiegoG Because sorting happens **after** the entries are traced. Trace them again after sorting took place.